# How to check what gets imported when you use import *

Tags: python, python-import

I am new to python. I have a very basic question. When we use the following command (I understand its not efficient to import everything using *)
from _ (*any module name*) import *

How can I check the things that get imported using the above command?

Comment: Under phython documentation you can see what "this" module has and how you can use it.

Comment: It is a package i installed from github. I can always go and look all the files in github package but I wanted a method to know what I imported using "*" command

Comment: @Pratik: This is exactly why you're discouraged from using `*` imports. You never know what `*` can drag into your global scope.

Comment: Also see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) to see what names are in the current module. By comparing the names before and after the import you can see what's imported:

```
>>> vars_before_import = set(dir())
>>> from json import *
>>> set(dir()) - vars_before_import
set(['load', 'JSONEncoder', 'dump', 'vars_before_import', 'JSONDecoder', 'dumps', 'loads'])
```

To exclude `vars_before_import`:

```
>>> set(dir()) - vars_before_import - {'vars_before_import'}
set(['load', 'JSONEncoder', 'dump', 'JSONDecoder', 'dumps', 'loads'])
```

**NOTE**

This won't catch objects that have been replaced (e.g. you defined `load` before importing everything in `json`).

Comment: Although a minor detail, this won't catch objects that have been replaced (e.g. you defined `load` before importing everything in `json`).

Comment: @Blender, Thank you for the comment. I missed that. I will update the answer to include your comment.